# Why does MS Word's algorithm for vertical positioning of super- and subscripts not conform to TeX's ?

Tags: fonts, opentype, knuth, math-table

Microsoft Office has, since 2007, used a formula layout algorithm based on the algorithm Knuth described in appendix G of the TeXbook.  But there's an apparent divergence in the final output from the description.  The algorithm that MSOffice uses is allegedly based on that as described in the *Open Type Math Table*.  Precise details of this can be found in the paper **Open Type Illuminated** by Ulrik Vieth (obtainable from the Netherlands' TUG at http://www.ntg.nl/maps/38/03.pdf).

For a screen resolution of 96dpi and a font size of 11pt, the algorithm says to shift the superscript baseline relative to the original baseline by 5 pixels, and the subscript by 3 pixels (up and down, respectively).  (For a more precise description of what the algorithm says in this case, please see https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckGL5.png.)

The figure below contains a blown up view of various renderings, with Word's view on the left, the algorithmic reconstruction in the middle, and TeX's rendering on the right:

[image: renderings of a^y_y]

The three horizontal lines are not from the figures, but are added to highlight the difference and parallelisms between them.

As can be seen in the image, the result obtained for the formula `$a^y_y$` following the algorithm described above is different from the result obtained from MS Word.  As can also be seen, the algorithm conforms to TeX's implementation fairly well (given the inaccuracies inherent in producing these diagrams, "fairly well" could mean "precisely" here).

Is there another algorithm at work here?  Has Knuth's algorithm been superseded?  Or is it simply that when placing the superscript `y` then MSWord chooses to place the *bottom* of the `y` at the superscript baseline instead of the baseline of the `y`?

Comment: Sorry, I find your question rather confusing. Are you here to discuss the paper you cite, or do you have a specific problem we can help you to solve? In the former case, this may not be the appropriate place. In the latter, please supply an minimum example of your TeX code and describe why you believe the results are incorrect. We may then be able to help you better.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how the algorithm for positioning subscripts and superscripts work for a single character according to the Open Type Math Tables from MS. From what I've read so far, this algorithm should be pretty close to the one used by Tex, as you can see in page 45 of Bogusław Jackowski's paper, which can be found at www.ntg.nl/maps/34/09.

Comment: This question seem not to be about TeX and is therefore off-topic. Typesetting algorithms in general or for MS Word in particular are not on-topic. Could you please clarify it further, otherwise it will be closed.

Comment: Looks to me like you should file a bug report at microsoft instead.

Comment: @Martin I posted this question because I need some help and I thought that could be of some interest of some of the users on this forum. If you think the question should be closed, please feel free to do it.

Comment: @Taco If you look at pg 16 of Ulrik Vieth's paper, you'll see the equivalence : SubSuperscriptGapMin = 4 * epsilon_8, where I believe epsilon_8 is probably equal to 1, at an 11 pts size font. Thus, this equivalence is saying that the constant SubSuperscriptGapMin should be 4 instead of 2. With this new value, the superscript would have to be lifted by more 2 pixels, according to another constant in the Math Table, SuperscriptBottomMaxWithSubscript = 5, which would bring the formula closer to the MS Word result, but still not exactly equal to it. Could you comment on this ?

Comment: You should close my prior question which was also about the OpenType Math Table and as I can see it today has 8 positive votes.

Comment: @bellachio: I don't think this question is parallel to the other question, which was about nomenclature of fonts used by Tex engines.  I do find this question interesting, although I couldn't answer it: I've asked a question on Meta about whether this question should be reopened, and there it is not clear exactly what information you are looking for.

Comment: @charles stewart: looks to me like we are still discussing pixel differences in the ms word screen view compared to the ms specification for the supposed behaviour. Suitable for 'forum.microsoft.com', assuming they have such a thing, but off topic here.

Comment: @bellochio: the opentype specification calculates in 'font units' of which, in the case of cambria, there are 2048 per 10 points. From that, it should be obvious that there absolutely no guarantee that <some value that rounds to 1 pixel> times 4 is actually equal to 4 pixels.

Comment: @Taco: It's not about rendering, it is about the choice of parameters used in a realisation of the formula layout algorithm described in appendix G of the Texbook.  It took me quite a bit of time to figure this out.

Comment: @Charles: I do not think so. This is about MS word not doing what the MS Math specification says it should do. This question has nothing to do with TeX except that the MS Math algorithm was explained in Ulrik's paper by using a comparison to the TeX algorithm.

Comment: @Taco: You certainly will understand Ulrik's paper much better than I.  However, I've read in several places that the Microsoft algorithm is based on Knuth's appendix G algorithm, which IMO makes it relevant for this site: not about Tex the engine, but Tex as an umbrella term for Knuthian typesetting, in the same way that Mathjax is accepted on this site.  I guess this is better discussed on the Meta thread, http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1415/a-comparative-typesetting-question

Answer (score 12):

The question ends with:

> Or is it simply that when placing the superscript y then MSWord chooses to place the bottom of the y at the superscript baseline instead of the baseline of the y?

I think this analysis spot on.

The *Open Type Math Table* documented algorithm is identical to TeX's algorithm in this case. There are a few other mathematical constructs where there are indeed differences, but both algorithms are identical in the case of script placement. This can also be seen in the included image, where **Alt** and **TeX** indeed appear identical (within rounding limits).

So, what we have here is MS Word not following the suggested behaviour as published in the *Open Type Math Table* documentation (also by Microsoft), and therefore I conclude this is a bug in MS Word and as such should be reported to Microsoft (by someone who actually cares, i.e. not *me*).

Comment: Surely if the suspicion is that Word uses the bottom of the y instead of the baseline, this would be very easy to check: simply repeat the comparison using a superscript without a descender, such as `$a_y^x$`. I don't have a recent version of word to test this.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer the question but maybe this rules out one of the possibilities:

[image: a rendered in Word 2007]

This is a rendering of Word 2007, as `y` and `x` are one the same baseline the bottom of `y` is not the decisive element. A comparable TeX rendering shows that the exponents are typeset quite a bit lower than in the Word 2007 case as shown in the image in the question.